# Google Sheets - Dragging n rows containing formulas

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a range of formulas like this:

[image: 0]

The range is exactly 15 rows with formulas and 1 empty row, a total of 16 rows per range.

If I highlight these 16 rows and then drag down, the next 16 rows will look like this:

[image: 0]

Meaning, row 18 will reference AC18 from the other sheet.

Instead of that, I would like it to function like this:

[image]

Meaning it references the next row on the other sheet, in this case, AC3, AC4, etc.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I can't share that exact sheet, but I recreated the problem in a dummy file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T5EeF2llLaKzyusCqYYFMbJNjE_i3K-WV7gm5RaYUAk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I couldn't see how your dummy file related to your question

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise with both my question and the dummy file. I solved the issue with a mass find and replace. Not elegant, but it's fine for right now.  @player0 i forgot to say thank you for editing the image links in the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this into **Sheet2!A2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 "♠"&Sheet1!A2&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(Sheet1!B2, ",")))),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]

---

paste this into **Sheet1!A18**, **Sheet1!A34** etc.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 "♠"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))+2)&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(
     INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"&COUNTUNIQUE(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))+2), ",")))),,999^99)), 
 "♠")), "♦")))
```

[image: 0]